# Can I protect against SQL injection attacks by wrapping SQL in PostgreSQL functions?

Tags: postgresql, security, sql-injection, quoting

Can I use a function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION create_user(_firstName text)
RETURNS void AS $$
  INSERT INTO user_account (first_name) VALUES (_firstName);
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

On the server to protect against SQL injection attacks? Then I can just run this on the client,

```
client.query(`SELECT create_user(${someUserInput})...`
```

Or will I still need to use [*parameterized queries* with placeholders,](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query)

```
client.query(`SELECT create_user($1)`, [someUserInput])
```

Comment: @EvanCarroll -- Why move it to DBA?  This isn't really a question about DB administration, architecture, or query optimization.  Seems like a better fit on SO, no?

Comment: Fair point.  That said, I think I'll keep the question here for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem (exploit)

```
client.query(`select create_user(${someUserInput})`
```

The problem there is what happens if

```
let someUserInput = `'foo'); DROP DATABASE bar;`;
```

That will get sent to your call as,

```
client.query("select create_user('foo'); DROP DATABASE bar;")`
```

And, that would be bad. Yes, the argument to `create_user` is protected against injection, but the call to that isn't.

## Solutions

1. Use placeholders (obvious choice: most failsafe and secure solution.)
2. Ensure `someUserInput` is properly quoted

   1. Use the client-library to quote it with something like [`PQescapeLiteral`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-ESCAPE-STRING)
   2. Use a second run to the server to quote it with [`quote_literal`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) (requires placeholders anyway). `SELECT quote_literal($1);`

I would not try to create the quoting-mechanism myself.